# How do I use the includes method in lodash to check if an object is in the collection?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, lodash

lodash lets me check for membership of basic data types with `includes`:

```
_.includes([1, 2, 3], 2)
> true
```

But the following doesn't work:

```
_.includes([{"a": 1}, {"b": 2}], {"b": 2})
> false
```

This confuses me because the following methods that search through a collection seem to do just fine:

```
_.where([{"a": 1}, {"b": 2}], {"b": 2})
> {"b": 2}
_.find([{"a": 1}, {"b": 2}], {"b": 2})
> {"b": 2}
```

What am I doing wrong?  How do I check for the membership of an object in a collection with `includes` ?

edit: 
question was originally for for lodash version 2.4.1, updated for lodash 4.0.0

Comment: `_.contains` has been removed in lodash v4 - use [`_.includes`](https://lodash.com/docs#includes) instead

Comment: @BillyMoon woops! yeah you're right, lodash v4.0.0 (released 2016-01-12) removes the `contains` alias. I'll update this

Answer (score 286, accepted):

The [`includes`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#includes) (formerly called `contains` and `include`) method compares objects by reference (or more precisely, with `===`). Because the two object literals of `{"b": 2}` in your example represent *different* instances, they are not equal. Notice:

```
({"b": 2} === {"b": 2})
> false
```

However, this will work because there is only one instance of `{"b": 2}`:

```
var a = {"a": 1}, b = {"b": 2};
_.includes([a, b], b);
> true
```

On the other hand, the [`where`](https://lodash.com/docs/3.10.1#where)(deprecated in v4) and [`find`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#find) methods compare objects by their properties, so they don't require reference equality. As an alternative to `includes`, you might want to try [`some`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#some) (also aliased as `any`):

```
_.some([{"a": 1}, {"b": 2}], {"b": 2})
> true
```

Answer (score 17):

Supplementing the answer by `p.s.w.g`, here are three other ways for achieving this using `lodash` `4.17.5`, **without using** `_.includes()`:

Say you want to add an object `entry` to an array of objects `numbers`, only if  `entry` does not exist already.

```
let numbers = [
    { to: 1, from: 2 },
    { to: 3, from: 4 },
    { to: 5, from: 6 },
    { to: 7, from: 8 },
    { to: 1, from: 2 } // intentionally added duplicate
];

let entry = { to: 1, from: 2 };

/* 
 * 1. This will return the *index of the first* element that matches:
 */
_.findIndex(numbers, (o) => { return _.isMatch(o, entry) });
// output: 0


/* 
 * 2. This will return the entry that matches. Even if the entry exists
 *    multiple time, it is only returned once.
 */
_.find(numbers, (o) => { return _.isMatch(o, entry) });
// output: {to: 1, from: 2}


/* 
 * 3. This will return an array of objects containing all the matches.
 *    If an entry exists multiple times, if is returned multiple times.
 */
_.filter(numbers, _.matches(entry));
// output: [{to: 1, from: 2}, {to: 1, from: 2}]
```

If you want to return a `Boolean`, in the first case, you can check the index that is being returned:

```
_.findIndex(numbers, (o) => { return _.isMatch(o, entry) }) > -1;
// output: true
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use `find` to solve your problem

https://lodash.com/docs/#find

```
const data = [{"a": 1}, {"b": 2}]
const item = {"b": 2}


find(data, item)
// (*): Returns the matched element, else undefined.
```