# Check object for certain value using lodash

Tags: lodash

I want to check if a certain property has a certain value using lodash. The code below prints out false. How can I check the value correctly?

[code example](https://repl.it/repls/ProbableJaggedNature)

```
const ob = {
 archived:true,
 done: true
}

console.dir(_.includes(ob.archived, true));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use the includes method in lodash to check if an object is in the collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25171143/how-do-i-use-the-includes-method-in-lodash-to-check-if-an-object-is-in-the-colle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `_.includes` directly with the object, here's an example of that:

```
const ob = {archived:true};

_.includes(ob, true); // true
```

If you have to check for a single value only you can use this:

```
const ob = {archived:true, done: true};

_.includes(_.pick(ob, ['archived']), true); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`_.matchesProperty()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#matchesProperty). The method generates a function, that accepts an object, and returns `true` if the object contains the stated property and value.

```js
const hasArchivedTrue = _.matchesProperty('archived', true)

const ob = {
 archived: true,
 done: true
}

console.log(hasArchivedTrue(ob)) // true
console.log(hasArchivedTrue({})) // false
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```