# lodash includes - disable strict checking

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an array like this

```
let a = ["1","2","3"];
let searchFor = 1;
_includes(a, searchFor); //this returns false
```

I think this one returns false because the value in array `a` are strings instead of number.

How can I disregard the data type?

I don't want to convert those strings in the array into numbers because some values in there might be strings really.

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you pass in a string type?

Comment: @Saddy i cannot control the types in the array and the value of `searchFor`.

Comment: See if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25171143/how-do-i-use-the-includes-method-in-lodash-to-check-if-an-object-is-in-the-colle helps

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own loose includes with `Array.some()` (or lodash's `_.some()`), and an abstract equality comparison (==):

```js
const loostIncludes = (arr, value) => arr.some(v => v == value)
  
console.log(loostIncludes(["1","2","3"], 1))
console.log(loostIncludes(["1","2","3"], "1"))
console.log(loostIncludes(["1","2","3"], 4))
```